# Which one is correct? "Explain what this is?" or "Explain what is this?"

Tags: grammar

- Please explain what is this?
  or
- Please explain what this is?

Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence, despite ending with a question mark (a period would be more correct), is an [imperative sentence](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/imperative-sentence-examples.html): "(You) please explain..."

Therefore, the noun comes before the verb and you say "Please explain **what this is**."

Answer (score -2):

***Please explain what this is?*** -

Comment: *Please explain what this is* is COMPLETELY CORRECT. The alternative sequence is "technically incorrect" even though it's not uncommon among native speakers (and I'd say it's actually *far more common* among certain classes of non-native speakers).

Comment: ok, I see, I edited it

Comment: If you are going to post an answer, you need more than to just echo part of the  question. Please state your reasoning and quote sources to justify it it possible.  And why, in this case, the OP's alternative is not correct.